# Rancher: ranchercli switch context in script not interactively

Tags: rancher, rancher-cli

I like to list all my contexts and switch to it from a command in my script, but it is interactively:

```
c:\\dist\\ranchercli\\rancher.exe context switch                                                 
NUMBER    CLUSTER NAME        PROJECT ID        PROJECT NAME   PROJECT DESCRIPTION
1 <all my projects listed>
2
3
4
:
Select a Project: (here I must enter a number, which is then saved to my cli2.json file)
```

my c:\.rancher\cli2.json only saves the active one,

If it is not active I get this error when accessing pods:

```
Error from server (Forbidden): pods is forbidden: User "u-vh3xagogyve" cannot list resource "pods" in API group ""
```

Nice it if was a direct `ranchercli context set <project-id>`

Answer (score 1):

Found you can just use the projectid:

```
c:\dist\ranchercli\rancher.exe context switch c-r6dht:p-hz4fq
time="2022-02-23T14:26:40+01:00" level=info msg="Setting new context to project Unregulated"
time="2022-02-23T14:26:40+01:00" level=info msg="Saving config to \\.rancher\\cli2.json"
```